# Check what app insight is linked to an azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I found this [documentaion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/app-insights/component/linked-storage?view=azure-cli-latest) which shows how to view a storage account linked to an app insight component.

Is there a way to do the opposite, meaning for a storage account which app insight is linked to it? I didn't really find it even in the portal itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have linked the `Application Insights` to `Storage Account`.

[image]

To check the `Application Insights` linked to Storage Account in Portal,

Navigate to the `Storage Account` => Under `Monitoring` select `Diagnostic settings` => Select the `Resource type` or select All.

We can see the list of `Application Insights` linked to `Storage Account`.

[image]

- Click on the Name of the `Resource`, here it is `FunctionApp1`.

[image]

Comment: It's strange that when I select all resource type i get an empty list, but when I clear the selection and nothing is selected at all, only then I see the resources

Comment: May be the list is not refreshed properly.